# Ejabberd MySQL bean files are not found

Tags: mysql, xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to install Ejabberd with mysql and followed this blog. 
https://www.ejabberd.im/Using%20ejabberd%20with%20MySQL%20native%20driver

but I can't find any bean files for MySQL

https://www.ejabberd.im/doc/display/CONTRIBS/Yxa

```
mysql.beam
mysql_auth.beam
mysql_conn.beam
mysql_recv.beam
```

I have configured all the other things other than copying bean files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you are referring to is obsolete. Use of MySQL with ejabberd is now fully integrated / packaged. If you build from source, you need to pass the proper --enable-mysql option. If using binary installer or packages from ProcessOne, the MySQL driver is already included.

What you need is to load schema into your database and configure "odbc" to use your MySQL database.

Comment: Master, maybe tag 15.09

Comment: Thanks Mickael i appreciate that. process one founder answered it I can't expect more then that.

Comment: Now I am getting error: 5.10.4 found, 6.1 (Erlang/OTP 17.1) required while configuring  but I installed erlang today using apt-get

Comment: Well, it problably mean apt-get did not install a version recent enough.

Comment: How can I get the latest one I tried to update but it says erlang is already the newest version.

Comment: You can download Erlang from erlang.org and compile it on your machine.

Comment: That helped. Thanks , Now i can move from openfire to scalable ejabberd